# XSLT Change delimiter from semicolon to comma and sort the values in alphabetical order

Tags: xslt

How to change the delimiter from semicolon to comma and sort the values in alphabetical order in XSLT? Please advise.

**Existing tags**

```
<component>
    <rate>T;P;C;X;R</rate>
</component>
```

**Expected tags**

```
<component>
    <rate>C,P,R,T,X</rate>
</component>
```

Comment: XSLT 1.0, 2.0 or 3.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part with changing the delimiter is easy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/component">
    <component>
      <rate>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(rate, ';', ',')"/>
      </rate>
    </component>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But, for the sorting part, it's a bit more challenging...

Answer (score 0):

If you can use XSLT 3.0, you can use `tokenize()`, `string-join()`, and `sort()`...

```
<xsl:template match="rate">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="string-join(sort(tokenize(normalize-space(),';')),',')"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

If you can use XSLT 2.0, you can use `tokenize()` and `string-join()`, but you'll have to use `xsl:sort` (or `xsl:perform-sort`) to do the sorting...

```
<xsl:template match="rate">
  <xsl:variable name="rates" as="item()*">
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(normalize-space(),';')">
      <xsl:sort data-type="text"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="string-join($rates,',')"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, Babelabout .. This helps. Unfortunately, we are on XSLT 1.0 and so can you pls advise how to get this done on sorting?

Comment: @DJayE Which XSLT 1.0 processor are you using?

Comment: @michael.hor257k A legacy server processes XSLT and transforms into a XML file for other systems. So had to live with XSLT 1.0

Comment: @DJayE - Do you know what XSLT processor your legacy server uses? I think Michael is asking so we know what extension functions might be supported.

Comment: @DJayE Daniel Haley is correct. If you don't know which processor it is, find out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244370/how-can-i-check-which-xslt-processor-is-being-used-in-solr/25245033#25245033

Comment: Just got to know that it allows 2.0 and so as suggested, I can try using tokenize and string-join ..

Comment: @DanielHaley What is "item()*" in the code snippet that you've shared?

Comment: @DJayE - That specifies that the variable `rates` is a sequence of zero or more items (nodes or atomic values).

Comment: Understood, Thanks @DanielHaley

Comment: @DanielHaley If I already have the "rate" tag in a variable say ''xyz", how to pass this "$xyz" into the code snippet of XSLT 2.0 that you've shared. Please help.

Comment: @DJayE - You could add a mode to the template from my answer (like `<xsl:template match="rate" mode="do-the-thing">`) and then apply-templates to the `$xyz` variable (like: `<xsl:apply-templates select="$xyz" mode="do-the-thing"/>`).

Comment: Some change happened with the requirement. There are individual <rate> tags and the input seems now like the below - `code`<component>
 <rate>X</rate>
 <rate>T</rate>
 <rate>C</rate>
 <rate>P</rate>
</component>
`code`
Expected output is 

`code' <rate>C,E,P,T,X</rate> `code` Please help on this.